# Getting the meta information of songs when fetching playlists

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm looking for a way to extract meta information (especially title and artist) from a youtube music playlist (the music service, not the videos). I can already fetch all playlists, and all items in the playlist. This per item information contains a title field, and a description field where some metadata seems to be included (but not really parseable). Is there a way to get the artist too, without extracting this from the description?

This is the request I currently use in Python:

```
request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
    part="snippet",
    maxResults=10,
    playlistId=playlistid
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been repeatedly inquired for here on SO.

Unfortunately, quite recent official Google staff accounts had acknowledged that [YouTube Data API does not produce such info](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122506827#comment4) through any of its endpoints (Feb 15, 2019):

> No user enters this data and is automatically updated by YouTube as per this - https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7680188#
>
> Changing this bug to a feature request, cannot comment on ETA :)

Later, by a post within the same thread, they rejected the feature request altogether (Aug 14, 2020):

> *Status: **Won't Fix (Infeasible)***

Comment: Thanks! It's too bad, the info is available on the website, so it seems technically possible. And for uploaded music, there is even no artist in the description...

Comment: Indeed, you're right: technically that's perfectly achievable. I don't have a clue why they *don't want* to make available that info via the YouTube Data API.